# jQuery not working for a newbie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been using bob tabors jQuery video tutorial [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Javascript-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Getting-Started-with-jQuery-14) for quite some time now and I can't get jQuery to work.

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>   
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
  <title>14. Getting Started with jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="title">14. Getting Started with jQuery</h1>

  <p id="first">
    <span>Now is the time for all good men to come to 
          the aid of their country.</span>
  </p>

  <p id="second">
    <strong>In the end these things matter most: 
       How well did you love? How fully did you live?</strong> 
  </p>

  <p id="third">
    <a id="myAnchor" href="http://www.learnvisualstudio.net">Visit my website</a>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
alert("thsdjasl");

}
```

But after html,no alert comes.

Comment: is `jquery.js` the jQuery source or the js you're showing at the bottom of the question?

Comment: check your console... you are missing a `);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the closing parentheses to your ready function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   alert("thsdjasl");
});
```

---

Without this your alert won't run and you will get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parentheses and semicolon. You should ideally use the "$" nomenclature for the document ready piece:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("thsdjasl");
```

});

Finally, you could have figured this out yourself by opening up the developer tools in your browser (Chrome is good), going to the javascript source tab and looking for errors and warnings that pop up.

Answer (score -2):

make sure your jquery.js file in the directory root . and use this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('bla bla ');
    alert('bla');
});
```

Comment: IT's in the same foled as the other files